# Get error : [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: socketProvider <- socket <- LogCtrl

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am new to AngularJs and nodejs and I have a simple chat app with angular as client and socketio as server side. I got an error when loading angular page

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: socketProvider <- socket <- LogCtrl
```

My client side

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript">
     socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337/');
     angular.module('Log',['ngRoute'])

             .controller('LogCtrl',['$scope','socket','$location', function($scope,socket,$location){

                 console.log('ok baby !!');

                 $scope.addUser = function(){
                     socket.emit('init',$scope.user);
                     $location.path("/view/index.html");
                 };

             }]);
 </script>

<body  ng-app = "Log" >
<div class=" main"  ng-controller = "LogCtrl" style = "width: 300px; ">
<fieldset>
     <form  ng-submit = "addUser()">
         <h2 >Hello!!</h2>
         <input ng-model = "user" required  style = "width: 200px; " placeholder = "Nhập tên của bạn" >
         <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
    </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Please help me what wrong with my client

---

I try to redirect to index.html by adding some codes

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
                 $routeProvider.
                             when('/main', {
                                 templateUrl: 'view/index.html',
                                 controller: 'ChatCtrl'
                             })
                 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                     enabled: true,
                     requireBase: false
                 });
                 }])

             .controller('LogCtrl',['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location){

                         console.log('ok baby !!');

                         $scope.addUser = function(){
                             socket.emit('init',$scope.user);
                             $location.path("/main");
                         };
                     }]);
```

but it not working, alway reload that side (log.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket shouldn't be there in dependency of controller, because it is an variable which you has declared outside the script globally. service, factory, provide, constant, value, etc. are only available for injecting dependency.

**Code**

```
.controller('LogCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    console.log('ok baby !!');

    $scope.addUser = function() {
        socket.emit('init', $scope.user);
        $location.path("/view/index.html");
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Tks a lot, you save my life :v

Comment: Just what I need it to fix it